# Setting up Gruntjs/Gulp and Travis CI

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp, travis-ci

When developing browser add-ons for multiple browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, and Opera it is often annoying to build the packages for the varying browsers.

Many extensions seem to be using projects like [Gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) to build the required files. Projects like [Reddit Enhancement Suite](https://github.com/honestbleeps/Reddit-Enhancement-Suite/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) have grunt files.

I am wondering how you setup a grunt file to build for all of the browsers like the Reddit Enhancement Suite does?

I keep coming up empty when searching for such topics/tutorials on Google.

Comment: How about doing it like RES? i.e. one directory per browser and one grunt task per browser.

Comment: @DominicJodoin by the looks of how they do it they have the main code outside of the browser folders and then browser dependant code within each browser folder. My extension is much simpler and it is really just the packaging that varies. I am looking for a much simpler kind of process than this one. RES is pretty advanced compared to what I am doing.